# My first beamerposter, portuguese language not working

Tags: beamer, hyphenation, babel, posters

I'm trying to make a poster based off the example in this site: http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php and using the this theme http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/download/beamerthemeIcy.sty

When I try changing the title to something with portuguese accents (with [portuguese]{babel}), the output is this
[image]

One blank page and <strike>some gibberish</strike>. Again, I only changed the titled of the exampled posted on that website.

It's my first poster and i'm kinda lost..

forgot to mention: I'm using TeXLive 2010 under Arch Linux

Example:

.tex file http://pastebin.com/HeQe02S2
  .sty theme file http://pastebin.com/mHNa0Dg4

This combination isn't working so well for me. Also: I need to use the beta symbol throught the text, but i can't make it Sans Serif (helvet).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem. Also, add any error messages that you get after compilation of the example code.

Comment: adding `\usepackage{utf8} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` fixed the gibberish but I still don't have word breaking support, and thus proper line breaking.

Comment: @Santiago: change the line input encoding: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. That should fix the problem. (Unless you're getting errors from missing images etc. from the original example.)

Comment: yes that fixed it, but hyphenization isn't working and, as a consequence, line breaking is ugly  (columns aren't | |)

Comment: @Santiago: it's hard to guess what the problem might be with no actual code (the code you posted shows no hyphenation problems); as I suggested before, post a minimal working example illustrating your hyphenation issues.

Comment: ok I added both .tex and .sty files in a simple way. I think the culprit is the theme file..

Comment: making $\beta$ NOT italic and helvetica is starting to be my most frustrating experience with latex so far... I have latin characters now (except in the footnote, which is set in the .sty file), only good line breaking (maybe there's no such thing in beamer?) and sans-serif (helvetica) math left to fix

Comment: @Santiago Your are most likely to find solutions here by asking specific questions and providing a small example inline that demonstrates your problem. The font problem is unrelated to the hyphenation problem and would be best addressed separately. At this point it is no longer clear which of your problems with hyphenation still exist.

Comment: have you added the line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`? It is necessary for hyphenation to work.

Answer (score 2):

Besides loading babel with the `portuguese` option, you should also add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

which fixes the issue with non-ascii characters being displayed as "gibberish" (original comment by Alan Munn) and

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

which is necessary for the hyphenation to work (original comment by Mateus Araújo).

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your latex, what appears into the output regarding `Babel` and hyphenation?

In my case this is what I get:

```
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, catalan, croatian, ukenglish, usenglishmax, galician, spanish, loaded.
```

I have written documents with beamer and latex in Spanish and English, and a beamerposter in English, and I've had no problem so far related to hyphenation.